# Joining 4 Tables with different conditions

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I use vb.net 2012 and msaccess2016 as database. I Have 4 tables. Item master,closing,Purchase,Issue. Now I want to get the result for a period in below formatted datagridview. Below are columns.

- Item Name(Item Master)
- Category(Item Master)
- Unit(Item Master)
- Sum of Quantity(closing)
- Sum of Quantity(Purchase)
- Sum of Quantity(Issue)

I have create a query with Item master and Closing and it's working. But when I try to purchase or issue there is no data. Purchase and issue table got no data.

```
Dim sdate, edate As Date
    sdate = dtsdate.Value
    edate = dtedate.Value

    Dim sqlSelect As String = "SELECT itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit," _
                              & " Sum(Closing.Qty) AS Opening FROM itemmaster INNER JOIN Closing ON " _
                              & "itemmaster.[Item Name] = Closing.[Item Name] WHERE(((Closing.closeDate) >= #" & sdate & " # And (Closing.closeDate) <=#" & edate & " #))" _
                              & " GROUP BY itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit"


    Try
        Dim con As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Dsn=sdbinventory;"
        Dim dt As New DataTable("user2")
        Using cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sqlSelect, con)
            con.Open()
            Dim da As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sqlSelect, con)
            da.Fill(dt)
            con.Close()
        End Using
        dgtvreport.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw
    End Try
```

Can you please help me to add rest two columns.
Thanks

[image]

My query

```
    PARAMETERS sdate DateTime, edate DateTime;
SELECT itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit, Sum(Closing.Qty) AS SumOfQty1, Sum(Purchase.Qty) AS SumOfQty, Sum(Issue.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
FROM ((itemmaster INNER JOIN Closing ON itemmaster.[Item Name] = Closing.[Item Name]) INNER JOIN Issue ON itemmaster.[Item Name] = Issue.[Item Name]) INNER JOIN Purchase ON itemmaster.[Item Name] = Purchase.[Item Name]
WHERE (((Closing.closeDate)>=[sdate] And (Closing.closeDate)<=[edate]) AND ((Purchase.PDate)>=[sdate] And (Purchase.PDate)<=[edate]) AND ((Issue.Idate)>=[sdate] And (Issue.Idate)<=[edate]))
GROUP BY itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit;
```

I have tried to run it in access. Also have added sample data. I just want to import all item names,category and unit from itemmaster. Now I want to add opening stock in next column and purchase and issue. I want to create and itemwise report.

Like

```
Item Name      Category     Unit     Opening     Purchased     Issued   Balance

  item1         Grocery      Kg        2           3               4       1

  item2         beverages    PCS       0           1               1       0

  Item3         vegetables   kg        2           0               0       2

  item4         consumable   Pkt       10          2               1       11
```

Comment: Have you verified that there actually is matching data in those two tables?

Comment: Yes all have a common field as Item Name. but purchase and issue table has no data.

Comment: If the tables have no data, why would you expect a query to return anything?

Comment: Add sample data for the four tables and the query you tried for joining the tables

Comment: Tell us your foreign keys.

Comment: INNER JOIN requires associated data in both tables on each side of the join for any record to return. Perhaps you should use LEFT or RIGHT JOIN? Use option 'show all records from ItemMaster and only those from [other table] that match' in Access query designer.

Comment: can you please write the sql statement. I am new to this.

Comment: I might could, but I won't. Use the Access query designer to help get the correct syntax. Click on the link lines between tables to open the relationships dialog. However, your WHERE clause is unnecessarily long. Only use the Closing dates as filter criteria.

Comment: I have tried and successfully run but when I include the date as criteria it only give me the records from second table.  SELECT itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit, Sum(Purchase.Qty) AS SumOfQty
FROM itemmaster LEFT JOIN Purchase ON itemmaster.[Item Name] = Purchase.[Item Name]
GROUP BY itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit;

Comment: PARAMETERS sdate DateTime, edate DateTime;
SELECT itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit, Sum(Purchase.Qty) AS SumOfQty
FROM itemmaster LEFT JOIN Purchase ON itemmaster.[Item Name] = Purchase.[Item Name]
WHERE (((Purchase.PDate)>=[sdate] And (Purchase.PDate)<=[edate]))
GROUP BY itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit;

Comment: SELECT itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit, Sum(Closing.Qty) AS SumOfQty1, Sum(Purchase.Qty) AS SumOfQty, Sum(Issue.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
FROM ((itemmaster LEFT JOIN Purchase ON itemmaster.[Item Name] = Purchase.[Item Name]) LEFT JOIN Issue ON itemmaster.[Item Name] = Issue.[Item Name]) LEFT JOIN Closing ON itemmaster.[Item Name] = Closing.[Item Name]
GROUP BY itemmaster.[Item Name], itemmaster.Category, itemmaster.Unit;

Comment: @June7 I have tried but when add the date it only returns the specific rows. can you help

Comment: If you need records from each table filtered by its own parameters, then need 4 queries and then join the queries.

Comment: I know that I can use four query and create a data table or datagridview from the result, but I'm searching for any other option like a single query. Anyway I have learn lot from this. thanks @June7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@june7 yes I belive your is the best answer which is also know by me but I have searched if there is any other option and in this process you have really gave me the in depth knowledge and differences about the different type of queries. thanks.